# "for" loop for functions

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following dataset with +7000 cities, divided by 21 age classes group. The columns are "City" "City Code" (unique) "Age Class" "N" and "D".
I have to apply two functions for every city. I was wondering if it's possible to write a `for` loop to do that automatically.

The dataset is the following:

```
City      City Code   Class     N      D
...
Rome       5800       95     6633   1900
Milano     1500       0      5000     7
Milano     1500       1     21900     2
Milano     1500       5     28000     1
...                  ...             ...
Milano     1500      90     12000    2000
Milano     1500      95     10000    1490
Venice     2700      0        742     3
...
```

For each city I have to do the following procedure: 
(**TOPALS_fit** and **e0** are the functions that I mentioned before)

```
boundaries=c(0,1,seq(5,100,5))
N<-Milano$N
D<-Milano$D
names(N) = names(D) = head(boundaries,-1)

fit = TOPALS_fit(N,D,std,
                 age_group_bounds = boundaries,
                 details=TRUE)

h<-e0(fit$logm)
>h
[1] 85.27
```

("fit" is a list of 12, and I'm interested in "logm")

The thing is that for every city I find a value, and I need an output like this:

```
City code      City             h
                ...
5800            Rome           84.5
1500            Milan          85.27
2700           Venice          84.38
                 ...
```

I don't know if it's possible to do that with a loop or something else (?)
Any help would be really really appreciated.

Comment: Are you subsetting your total data frame in order to get a data frame Milano, Rome, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demonstrates it. The for-loop cycles through the cities. You get the
list of cities with `unique(TotalDf[["City"]])`. The code is commented
and explains itself (I hope).

Please note: in order to make it executable I had to mock some variables and functions.

```r
# Sample data 
TotalDf <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
  City    CityCode   Class     N      D
  Rome       5800       95     6633   1900
  Milano     1500       0      5000     7
  Milano     1500       1     21900     2
  Milano     1500       5     28000     1
  Milano     1500      90     12000    2000
  Milano     1500      95     10000    1490
  Venice     2700      0        742     3")

# Mock function for demonstration purpose
TOPALS_fit <- function(N, D, std, age_group_bounds, details) {
  return(list(alpha = NA, D = D, N = N, std = std, logm = runif(1)))
}

# Mock function for demonstration purpose
e0 <- function(x) x

# Mock variable for demonstration purpose
std <- NA

# Allocate memory
ResultDf <- data.frame(
  CityCode = integer(length(unique(TotalDf[["City"]]))),
  City     = unique(TotalDf[["City"]]),
  h        = numeric(length(unique(TotalDf[["City"]])))
)

# 
boundaries <- c(0,1,seq(5,100,5))


for (City in unique(TotalDf[["City"]])) {
  # Subset data
  Data <- TotalDf[TotalDf["City"] == City, ]
  
  # Do your usual computations
  N <- Data$N
  D <- Data$D
  # names(N) <- names(D) <- head(boundaries, -1) # omitted for demo purpose
  
  fit = TOPALS_fit(N, D, std,
                   age_group_bounds = boundaries,
                   details=TRUE)
  
  h <- e0(fit$logm)
  
  # Put results into results data frame
  CityCode <- unique(TotalDf[TotalDf["City"] == City, "CityCode"])
  ResultDf[ResultDf[["City"]] == City, ] <- list(CityCode, City, h)
}
# Show result
ResultDf
#>   CityCode   City          h
#> 1     5800   Rome 0.24561078
#> 2     1500 Milano 0.01275526
#> 3     2700 Venice 0.25215130
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>